# Linux old passwd file - reversing

Tags: linux, embedded-linux

I'm currently trying to "hack" a linux embedded device. This device has a telnet daemon which is not supposed to be used. Anyway, I've taken the binary firmware from the manufacter website and have successfuly extracted the root filesystem. By the way, i have now the /etc/passwd file.

The passwd file looks like that :

root:{10 char long}:0:0:root:/bin:/bin/sh

My question is : What type of hash could it be ? a crypt() hash method would return a string of 13 char.

If I know the hash method, i could either bruteforce or replace it ...

Thank you very much

Comment: What character set is the hash made out of? Any special characters like = at the end?

Answer (score 6):

Usually the password hash contains the salt and used hashing algorithm. If the salt does not start with `$` DES is used to encrypt the password.

Quoting from the [crypt(3) manpage](http://kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/crypt.3.html):

> If salt is a character string starting with the characters "$id$"
>   followed by a string terminated by "$":
>
> ```
>   $id$salt$encrypted
> ```
>
> then instead of using the DES machine, id identifies the encryption
>   method used and this then determines how the rest of the password
>   string is interpreted.  The following values of id are supported:
>
> ```
>   ID  | Method
>   ---------------------------------------------------------
>   1   | MD5
>   2a  | Blowfish (not in mainline glibc; added in some
>       | Linux distributions)
>   5   | SHA-256 (since glibc 2.7)
>   6   | SHA-512 (since glibc 2.7)
> ```

You should be able to set the password 'test' by inserting e.g. (md5 and empty salt):

```
$1$$098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to figure the format out by hand.  Generally if you take the passwd file and pass it directly to [John The Ripper](http://www.openwall.com/john/) it will auto-detect and brute force the password for you.

Comment: That's true but in this case, john returns to me "no password loaded" when filling it the passwd file :/

Comment: Are you using the latest ubuntu "john", or downloaded & installed from source? If I remember correctly ubuntu's is out of date and the latest version from source is smarter at auto-detection.